# .csv file regular expressions

Tags: regex, csv, lua

I'm currently just starting my first Lua program and I have a .csv file to read in. I want to check if the file I'm reading in is truely a .csv file.

I've tried regex similiar to these but they just don't work..

```
s = string.match(arg[1], "%A+\.csv$")
```

whats the correct way to do the regex in lua?

Comment: Since you have the filename, check if the last 4 characters are .csv. I don't know LUA, but something along the lines of substr()

Comment: Well I want to make sure that the file starts with a letter. So I need the %A at the front. But when I do .csv$ it's supposed to check the last 4 and see if its .csv but it doesn't :(

Comment: Note: That is not a regular expression. That's a *pattern*. They're not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Lua patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1), you escape the meaning of a special character by using `%`, not `\`. Also, `%A` means a *non*-letter; a *letter* is `%a` (lowercase). So you seem to want one of these:

```
"^%a+%.csv$"             <-- one or more letters, plus ".csv"
"^%a.*%.csv$"            <-- a letter, plus zero or more characters, plus ".csv"
```

Comment: so the % operator also serves as a delimeter for regex? Thats kind of interesting..

Comment: well I also read that %A means all upper and lowercase letters... which is what i need

Comment: nevermind. %a means all letters %l is lower and %u is upper. Derp..thanks!

Comment: @cj1098: You're welcome! You may find http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1 useful in sorting this stuff out. :-)